# How load local gpx file in a openLayer map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I think than the title is pretty clear, I am using openLayer library(v4.6.5) and I am trying to load a local GPX file in my map when the page is loaded. In the official documentation, in GPX Data example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/gpx.html?q=data) that seems to be pretty straightforward to do with an url.

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/gpx/fells_loop.gpx',
      format: new ol.format.GPX()
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
      return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    }
  });
```

My question is, instead of setting url option, what option I need to set in ol.source.Vector object to load a local GPX file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Just use the drag & drop component provided within OpenLayers library. Demo at
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html (drag and drop a GPX to test)

**Solution 2**

If you want/need to do things manually, you need to remove the URL reference and the format.

Then, you get GPS file content when you do a drag and drop (or another action) then parse it with

```
var GPXfeatures = (new ol.format.GPX()).readFeatures('yourGPXstring', {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})
```

Then you add the features to the source with

```
vector.getSource().addFeatures(GPXfeatures)
```

Comment: Thanks! I choose Solution 2. So I got my GPX content file with a drag and drop (see drag and drop examples in documentation) in dragAndDropInteraction.on function I store event.features in the local storage but when I refresh my page and I replace 'yourGPXstring' by localStorage.getItem('<MyItem>') my interpretor tell me "TypeError: vector.getSource(...) is null". Indeed my GPXfeatures variables is an empty array whereas localStorage.getItem('<MyItem>') contain my content file. I try to JSON.stringify/JSON.parse my localStorage Item but I have the same issue.

Comment: You simply can't "store event.features". You need to convert your features to a string before storing them with something like `(new ol.format.GPX()).writeFeatures(event.features)` PS: you may need to play with `featureProjection`, `dataProjection` options (see API http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GPX.html#writeFeatures)